# AJAX script trigger firing on 2 separate input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I"m new to AJAX requests and having these fire when a form input field is modified. I've managed to get this working well with a date input field, but have just added a 2nd form to the page which also has a date input field and now the script is firing when both fields are modified. I need to disable this so it doesn't fire on the 2nd input field.

Here's the first input field:

```
        <td id="57944"><input type="text" id="985124" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ship Date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateShipped" value=""></td>
```

which fires this script when the date field is modified:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-control.datepicker").change(function(){
```

I've just added this 2nd input field:

```
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dateReceived" id="dateSigned" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Date Signed"></td>
```

which is also firing the same script. I can see that both have:

```
class="form-control datepicker"
```

which is presumably the reason the script is firing for both, but I'm not sure how to change the 2nd input so that it won't fire the script (or change the `$(".form-control.datepicker").change(function(){` part of the script so that it only fires when the first input is modified).

Comment: That do not select both, make a selector only to select the one....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try with name selector

```
$("input[name='dateShipped']").
 change(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector `.form-control.datepicker:eq(0)`

that will only select the first element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using event's for same class the event will trigger for both, either you can use

$(".form-control.datepicker:eq(0)").change(function(){});

or

$(".form-control.datepicker:first-child").change(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a class to the date fields for which you want to trigger the event. Then, make your class selector more specific when you wire up the event. This will make your code more scalable than using :eq() since you won't have to figure out which index is which control when you go to add more inputs.

```
<td id="57944"><input type="text" id="985124" class="form-control datepicker fire-event" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ship Date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateShipped" value=""></td>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form-control.datepicker.fire-event").change(function(event){
        // handle event
    });
});
```

Conversely, you could use the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector function if you would rather add a specific class to items you don't want firing a change event:

```
<td id="57944"><input type="text" id="985124" class="form-control datepicker no-change-event" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ship Date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateShipped" value=""></td>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form-control.datepicker").not(".no-change-event").change(function(event){
        // handle event
    });
});
```